# How to permanently rename C# project's Properties namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, rename

In another project I have classes that use the name `Properties` and thus it becomes a hassle to work with them when the pre-generated Settings' and Resources' Properties namespace gets in the way. Is there a way to force this namespace to stay renamed even after making modifications to resources or settings?

The following are the files causing issues.

*Resources.Designer.cs*

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ProjectNamespace.Properties {
    using System;
```

*Settings.Designer.cs*

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ProjectNamespace.Properties {
```

If it's not clear. I want to rename `Properties`, not `ProjectName`.

Comment: I added the files causing issues to the question.

Comment: I'm trying to change the 'Properties' namespace because it conflicts with a class. I can't rename it normally since these files are auto-generated and rename it back whenever they regenerate.

Comment: But renaming the project namespace does not change the `Properties` namespace. I'm aware that I can change the project namespace, that's not what I want to do.

Comment: The namespace used by these files is generated by a custom tool, which uses the string defined in the "Default Namespace" property of your project (which appears to be `ProjectNamespace.Properties`). I don't think there's any way around that. Can you show a sample of how this is causing a problem in your code?

Comment: `Properties` is ambiguous between the class named `Properties` in reference and the namespace `Properties` which I want nothing to do with.

Comment: If you look at your project properties, is the default namespaces specified as `ProjectNamespace.Properties`? Why not remove `Properties` from there?

Comment: `Properties` is not part of my default project namespace. It's appended to my project namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've added your `Settings` and `Resources` files through the project properties window, under the corresponding tabs (where you can add default files for these items). When you do it this way, the name `.Properties` is appended to the namespace, and they are organized under the `Properties` node of the project in the `Solution Explorer`:

[image]

Instead, try adding them as separate project items. To do this, right-click on your project, choose `Add --> New Item`, select the `General` heading under `Visual C# Items`, and then you can add a new `Resources File` and/or `Settings File`:

[image]

These files will be added to your project like any other item (not under the `Properties` node), and will use your project's default namespace, and will not add `.Properties` to it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I was able to manually rename their folder in explorer and in the project file and once the files regenerated they used the new namespace!